# Laravel and dependency Injection Scenario

Tags: php, dependency-injection, laravel, laravel-4

I have the following code

```
class FooBar
{
    protected $delegate;

    public function __construct( $delegate )
    {
        $this->delegate = $delegate;
    }
}

App::bind('FooBar', function()
{
    return new FooBar();
});

class HomeController extends BaseController 
{
    protected $fooBar;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->fooBar = App::make('FooBar');
        //HomeController needs to be injected in FooBar class
    }

}

class PageController extends BaseController 
{
    protected $fooBar;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->fooBar = App::make('FooBar');
        // PageController needs to be injected in FooBar class
    }

}
```

How can i inject the HomeController, PageController as a delegate in FooBar class ?

with the above code i get the a missing argument error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependency Injection in Laravel is as simple as that:

```
class FooBar
{
    protected $delegate;

    public function __construct( HomeController $delegate )
    {
        $this->delegate = $delegate;
    }
}

App::bind('FooBar', function()
{
    return new FooBar();
});

class HomeController extends BaseController 
{
    protected $fooBar;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->fooBar = App::make('FooBar');
    }

}
```

Home Controller will be instantiated and injected as $delegate.

**EDIT:**

But if you need to instantiate FooBar passing the instantiator (your controller) to it, you have to do it this way:

```
<?php

class FooBar
{
    protected $delegate;

    public function __construct( $delegate )
    {
        $this->delegate = $delegate;

        /// $delegate here is HomeController, RegisterController, FooController...
    }
}

App::bind('FooBar', function($app, $param) 
{
    return new FooBar($param);
});

class HomeController extends Controller {

    protected $fooBar;

    public function delegate()
    {
        $this->fooBar = App::make('FooBar', array('delegate' => $this));
    }

}
```

Comment: OK, both of you gave me a good answer, but the problem is that i will call App::make('FooBar') in several controllers and the calling controller has to be injected, in your answer this works only with HomeController, but what about PageController, ContactController ..etc

Answer (score 0):

Try This. (http://laravel.com/docs/ioc#automatic-resolution)

```
class FooBar
{
    protected $delegate;

    public function __construct( HomeController $delegate )
    {
        $this->delegate = $delegate;
    }
}

App::bind('FooBar', function($delegate)
{
    return new FooBar;
});
```